# ActivityNotFoundException on launching class that is in manifest

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-manifest

I have an app with the main class launching (or at least this is what I want to happen) two other classes.  The main class `WhenIGetToActivity` launches the fist class `CreateLoc` without error but throws an ActivityNotFoundException on trying to launch the second `Menu`.

Here is the relevant code from the `WhenIGetToActivity`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    return true;
}
...

public boolean onTap(final GeoPoint p, final MapView mapView) {
        boolean tapped = super.onTap(p, mapView);
        if (tapped) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateLoc.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        } else {
```

Both secondary classes are in the correct (and same) package, both `extends Activity`.

Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="SandS.Geo.Cal"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application>
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name=".WhenIGetToActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="CreateLoc" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="Menu" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is the Logcat

```
06-21 17:30:21.479: I/ApplicationPackageManager(3891): cscCountry is not German : XEU
06-21 17:30:22.289: W/TAG(3891): Location unknown
06-21 17:30:22.329: I/MapActivity(3891): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
06-21 17:30:22.329: E/MapActivity(3891): Couldn't get connection factory client
06-21 17:30:27.189: W/KeyCharacterMap(3891): No keyboard for id 0
06-21 17:30:27.189: W/KeyCharacterMap(3891): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-21 17:30:27.229: D/AndroidRuntime(3891): Shutting down VM
06-21 17:30:27.229: W/dalvikvm(3891): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {SandS.Geo.Cal/android.view.Menu}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at SandS.Geo.Cal.WhenIGetToActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(WhenIGetToActivity.java:62)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2158)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:325)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyDownPanel(PhoneWindow.java:570)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyDown(PhoneWindow.java:1220)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1727)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2627)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2602)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1874)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
06-21 17:30:27.239: E/AndroidRuntime(3891):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried Cleaning the Project.

Any ideas.

Following suggestions from 4 answers that I change the name of the class, I have done so it in now called `StevesToolsMenu.class`

The new `onCreateOptionsMenu` now has the line:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StevesToolsMenu.class);
```

The relevant part of the manifest file is now:

```
<application>
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name=".WhenIGetToActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CreateLoc" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".StevesToolsMenu" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

The new Logcat is:

```
06-23 15:14:22.989: I/ApplicationPackageManager(4088): cscCountry is not German : XEU
06-23 15:14:23.789: W/TAG(4088): Location unknown
06-23 15:14:23.849: I/MapActivity(4088): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
06-23 15:14:23.849: E/MapActivity(4088): Couldn't get connection factory client
06-23 15:14:30.219: W/KeyCharacterMap(4088): No keyboard for id 0
06-23 15:14:30.219: W/KeyCharacterMap(4088): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-23 15:14:30.289: I/ApplicationPackageManager(4088): cscCountry is not German : XEU
06-23 15:14:30.319: D/AndroidRuntime(4088): Shutting down VM
06-23 15:14:30.319: W/dalvikvm(4088): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{SandS.Geo.Cal/SandS.Geo.Cal.StevesToolsMenu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at SandS.Geo.Cal.StevesToolsMenu.onCreate(StevesToolsMenu.java:20)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     ... 11 more
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     ... 21 more
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:291)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:264)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:247)
06-23 15:14:30.329: E/AndroidRuntime(4088):     ... 24 more
```

We seem to have replaced one problem with another (or rather uncovered a second problem).

Whichever way you look at it, I still find it difficult to understand why one class should work and another (setup in seemingly the same way) class does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to start an activity named `android.view.Menu`. You do not have an activity named `android.view.Menu`. You have an activity that, for some reason, is named `SandS.Geo.Cal.Menu`.

> Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);

If you change the second parameter of the `Intent` constructor to the `Class` object for your activity, that will likely work better. Even better would be to not have an activity named `Menu`, but to use something more distinctive, to help prevent this sort of collision in the future.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean here.  Firstly the activity is called `SandS.Geo.Cal.Menu` because I wanted it named that; I have changed it to `SandS.Geo.Cal.StevesToolsMenu`, to prevent clashing with the `View.Menu`.
Secondly, if you take any time at all to look you will see that the second parameter of my Intent constructor IS `Menu.class` (now `StevesToolsMenu.class`).

Comment: @steve.watson128: "Secondly, if you take any time at all to look you will see that the second parameter of my Intent constructor IS Menu.class" -- I *did* take the time to look. You, however, apparently did not. Your error message was `Unable to find explicit activity class {SandS.Geo.Cal/android.view.Menu}`. Notice the reference to `android.view.Menu`. That is because you were trying to start `android.view.Menu` as an activity, because your `Menu.class` reference was resolving to `android.view.Menu`, because you were importing `android.view.Menu` and not your own `Menu` class.

Comment: @steve.watson128: With regards to your new error, `MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity` is a fairly straightforward error message. Android thinks that line #17 of whatever layout you are inflating references `MapView` and that your `StevesToolMenu` is not a `MapActivity`. If you are fairly certain that your layout does not reference `MapView`, try cleaning the project (Project > Clean in Eclipse or `ant clean` for command-line development), as occasionally Android's resource ID references get out of sync.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  You are right I hadn't looked closely enough, sorry for the smartass comment.  I had, in fact, loaded the wrong layout and that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

How about changing your activity in AndroidManifest.xml

The old one

```
<activity android:name="CreateLoc" ></activity>
<activity android:name="Menu" ></activity>
```

To

```
<activity android:name=".CreateLoc" ></activity>
<activity android:name=".Menu" ></activity>
```

Comment: In this case it doesn't work.  Also, Eclipse itself put in the "CreateLoc" entry, WITHOUT the dot.
In any case, see the amended question above, it has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that there already a `Menu` class defined in the Android library. If you're trying to open an Options Menu, you don't launch it as another activity with an `Intent`. You can either programmatically create a `Menu` or inflate a `Menu` from an XML file.

Comment: You are right, but changing the name has not resolved the problem.  See the amended question above.