# ActivityNotFoundException even though it is declared in Manifest

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I wrote a simple app involving two activities. I used an explicit intent to call the second activity, but it always force closes the app when I try to do so.
Code of 1st activity

```
public class Splash extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private ImageButton ibLogo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    ibLogo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    ibLogo.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, Menu.class));
}

}
```

Menu is in the same package as Splash

Android Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.rakeshsarangi.petrofiesta2013.Menu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu" >
</activity>
```

I have seen other threads like this but none could help me. Really baffled at this simple thing.

Comment: show your package structure and application package name

Comment: As how @Hi-Tech KitKat Android mentioned, show us your package structure or be sure that the `Menu` class is inside the package `com.rakeshsarangi.petrofiesta2013`

Comment: show us your menu class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably thinks that the menu from the line `startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, Menu.class));` is `android.view.Menu`. You should change the line to use the full name `com.rakeshsarangi.petrofiesta2013.Menu`.

Answer (score 1):

Change -

```
startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, Menu.class));
```

to -

```
startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, com.rakeshsarangi.petrofiesta2013.Menu.class));
```

I thin it is taking `Menu` class from `android.view`

Answer (score 0):

if you are extending Menu then this might be help full

as per commons-ware answer

You are trying to start an activity named **android.view.Menu**. You do not have an activity named **android.view.Menu**.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);
```

If you change the second parameter of the Intent constructor to the Class object for your activity, that will likely work better. Even better would be to not have an activity named Menu, but to use something more distinctive, to help prevent this sort of collision in the future.

[ActivityNotFoundException on launching class that is in manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141803/activitynotfoundexception-on-launching-class-that-is-in-manifest?rq=1)